# Combined nodes to a single one based on a common property

Tags: graph, neo4j, group-by, cypher

I'm trying to learn more about Neo4j. Is there a way to group nodes that have the same name/number/etc.?

In standard RDBMS one can use the "Group by" clause to combine specific values into one.  Have a look at the picture for a better understanding.

[image: Image HERE]

I'd like to combine these two nodes ("EE", "EE") into one, which has both sub-nodes.

Code for the image output:

```
match (A:Place)-[:`->`]-(B:Typ)
where A.name ='City1'
return A, B
```

Comment: May I ask why you're using a relationship type such as `->`, instead of encoding that information into the direction of the relationship?

Comment: Actually, your image reveals an interesting issue with `->` as a relationship type. The web UI can rotate the type of a relationship by 180°. It does not make much of a difference when the relationship type consists of the usual, letters, numbers and underscores - however, `->` rotated gives you exactly `<-`, which is very confusing.

Comment: Also, if you ever needed to have multiple relationship types, you'd have to come up with "normal" names for the new types anyway. Afterwards, the `->` type name would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

When you created your `Place` nodes, you should have used a [MERGE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) operation instead of [CREATE](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/create/). For example, no matter how many times you execute the following, it will not create a duplicate `Place` node if one already existed with the same `name`:

```
MERGE (a:Place {name: 'City1'})
...
```

Also, before you use the `MERGE` operation, you should make it work optimally by *first* creating an [index](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:Place(name)` (or a [uniqueness constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-unique-nodes) on the same node label and property).

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent for SQL's `GROUP BY` clause in Cypher, as it is done implicitly. So whenever you use an [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/), such as `count`, `sum`, `min` or `collect`, the rest of the variables in the tuple are grouped implicitly.

```
MATCH (a:Place {name: 'City1'})-[:`->`]-(b:Typ)
RETURN a.name, count(b)
```

However, it seems to me that you actually want to perform a *transformation* that combines parent nodes together (we could say that the nodes are "merged" together, but I would like to avoid that word, as there is a `MERGE` clause in Cypher with different semantics -- see @cybersam's answer for details).

1. Match for the required pattern.
2. Project to the property that will serve as a key for grouping and group.
3. Create a new parent node.
4. Create the `name` property to that node.
5. Add relationships to the new node.
6. Remove old parent nodes.

In practice, this could be implemented with a query like this:

```
MATCH (a:Place {name: 'City1'})-[:`->`]-(b:Typ)
WITH a.name AS name, collect(a) AS as, collect(b) AS bs
CREATE (new:Place {name: name})
WITH as, bs, new
UNWIND bs AS b
CREATE (new)-[:`->`]->(b)
WITH as
UNWIND as AS a
DETACH DELETE a
```

While the query is quite complex, fortunately, it is easy to test on a toy data set:

```
CREATE
  (:Place {name: 'City1'})-[:`->`]->(:Typ {name: 'B1'}),
  (:Place {name: 'City1'})-[:`->`]->(:Typ {name: 'B2'})
```

This results in:

[image]

And is combined to:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I would like to perform a transformation that combines parent nodes. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @DevMaster: I expanded my solution with such a query.

Comment: You are the best <3 This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you very much.

Comment: Just one more thing, it seems to work but the parent "node name" is missing. Any idea why?

Comment: You have to copy that (and possibly other properties) separately. I only noticed it when I added an example - it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you were not aware: if you are looking to permanently merge nodes into 1 merging the relationships too, you can use [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). If all the properties (except for the internal node id) are the same, then maybe.

```
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([node1, node2])
```